# S3: IAM vs Temporary credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am planning to use S3 for my application. I want to grant permission for users of my application to access data stored in S3 for sometime and they will use GET on the objects stored.

Can somebody explain which one is preferred and why for my requirement ??

Thanks in advance.

***UPDATE***

Both IAM and temporary credentials can generate the signature for URL. Is there any advantage in using one than other ??  Is my understanding correct w.r.t temporary credentials ??

Answer (score 0):

question is a bit misleading. 
you have 3 things here:
1) IAM credentials 
2) Temporary credentials via IAM STS
3) Presigned URL

If you do the presigned URL you can just provide the URL and the user can consume it before it expires.

It really does not matter if you are using permananent or temporary IAM credentials to generate the presigned URL as far as the URL is concerned.

If you are on an EC2 instance I would avocate for using an instance role and giving that the permissions needed to do the signing and let the sdk/cli handle it for you (it will under the hood use temporary credentials via IAM STS)

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, if you need to access to a S3 bucket from S3 Client for AWS SDK, I will use Temoporary credentials.
If you need to access to S3 bucket from a link of the webview, I will use Signed URLs.